# how to connect mysql server on external server in j2me application

Tags: mysql, android, java-me

I have a hosting account at godaddy ruinning Linux. Is has MySQL. I am creating a J2ME application that runs on android and I was wondering if there is any simpler way to connect from j2me application to my MySQL server?

Is it required to install anything at my server? which I cannot do because of the shared account. Any way to just open the connection, update some data in the MySQL from j2me application?

Comment: Android does not run J2ME apps.

Comment: I have writen a android j2me application and it runs fine. I dont understand what you are saying?

Comment: Which can't be true! Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#Issues_concerning_application_development You can only run J2ME application with an installed j2me emulator on the device (tried that myself... nothing I would recommend)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple. You just need to do HTTP application/x-url-form-encoded request on the midlet and set request property to HTTP.POST. Then stream form data as bytes. Receive those post variable using a server side language (i used PHP) like `$_POST['var']` and in that server script write MySQL query like insert into .. VALUES.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any DB drivers exist for J2ME. If you can't find them just make layer on the server and implement your own protocol for retrieving data via http or sockets